# Bootstrap по частям

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

На оффициальном сайте bootstrap можно скачать полную версию `bootstrap.css`, а как разделить весь код на части, ведь bootstrap состоит из многих вещей: сетка, всплывающие окна, тултипы, уведомления и т.д.

Ситуация такая: использую на своем сайте Bootstrap alerts https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp, стили для уведомлений (notify), но они идут в комлекте вместе со всем остальным, другие стили просто мешают, они перемешиваются и переназначаются, как можно отделить только нужную часть?

Comment: Откройте этот файл, посмотрите как там все реализовано и сделайте то же самое в своем отдельном  (условно `style.css`), что тут сложного?! И при этом не придется тоскать за собой *bootstrap*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На сайте Bootstrap можно кастомизировать загружаемые файлы и выбрать только те компоненты, которые нужны.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/225828)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да ладно?